# If it exists, .Remove() it, if not .Add() it

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have this action method that checks if an item exists, and if it does, it's to be removed. If it doesn't exist, it's to be added. It's like an on-off-switch for that particular item:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> FrontPageProduct(ViewModelFrontPageProduct frontPageProduct)
{
    var fpp = new FrontPageProduct()
    {
        ProductCategoryId = frontPageProduct.ProductCategoryId,
        ProductId = frontPageProduct.ProductId,
        SortOrder = 0
    };
    bool exists = _context.FrontPageProducts
        .Any(x => x.ProductCategoryId == frontPageProduct.ProductCategoryId 
        && x.ProductId == frontPageProduct.ProductId);
    if (exists)
    {
        var delete = (from d in _context.FrontPageProducts
                         where (d.ProductCategoryId == frontPageProduct.ProductCategoryId && 
                         d.ProductId == frontPageProduct.ProductId)
                         select d).FirstOrDefault();
        _context.Remove(delete);
    }
    else
    {
        _context.Add(fpp);
    }
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), new { id = fpp.ProductCategoryId, tab = 2 });
}
```

Now, I feel this is a bit long winded. Is there a shorter, but still readable way of doing this?

Comment: This sounds like a very bad design. You should have one Delete and one Create action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not have to use `Any` to determine whether it exists. Basically load it using `FirstOrDefault` (I used async as I see you use async in save, you can also use it in `FirstOrDefault`). If it is found you have an instance and you can delete it without additional load:

```
var fpp = new FrontPageProduct()
{
    ProductCategoryId = frontPageProduct.ProductCategoryId,
    ProductId = frontPageProduct.ProductId,
    SortOrder = 0
};

var fppDB = await _context.FrontPageProducts
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.ProductCategoryId == frontPageProduct.ProductCategoryId && x.ProductId == frontPageProduct.ProductId);

if (fppDB != null)
{
    _context.Remove(fppDB);
}
else
{
    _context.Add(fpp);
}

await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Otherwise you can also use SQL stored procedure and call this one from EF. It will be more efficient.